# Trying to paste a text using document.execCommand in a conteneditable Div. works in Chrome, not in IE. I am using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

For some processing, we have tapped into `ng-paste` event. prevented its default behavior. If the pasted text is valid (max length restriction) we need to remove all the formatting of that text and add the plain text into the `contenteditable div`/`span`

```
document.execCommand("insertText", false, inputText);
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, inputText);
```

Both these options work with Chrome.
In IE we are getting error from `$sce` service.

```
[$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.
```

I am totally out of clue right now. Any help is appreciated. Also if I am not clear, feel free to comment, I'll update the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no magic in IT. Always "use the source"! https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/sce.js#L365.

It shows, that the `$sce` tries to guard your site from inserting (probably malicious) urls. Have a look at the [Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce). It is not supported in IE8 with quirks mode, probably that's why your solution works there. Basically, you have two options:

1. [add specific urls to the Whitelist](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider)
2. [disable the `$sce` completely](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#can-i-disable-sce-completely-) (not recommended).

Comment: The clipboard text which is being added does not contain any URLs and the same text works fine in Chrome. As expected IE gives us the trouble.

Comment: ah, sorry, misread it. What version of IE? How plain is your text? Does it contain any special characters (`<`, `:`, `/`, etc.) or it is just letters?

Comment: pure letters. IE10 compatibility mode.